# BufferedReader specifications

Tags: java, jvm, try-catch, bufferedreader

Why do we need to put the readLine() method of BufferedReader inside a try{} block and catch(IOException e){} for that?

But in the case of using a Scanner object to take input does not require so.

Comment: did you go through the javadocs for both?

Comment: You get a different exception which is not checked. Scanner is designed as a higher level interface for developers who don't know what to do with exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for Scanner:

> A scanner can read text from any object which implements the Readable
>   interface. If an invocation of the underlying readable's
>   Readable.read(java.nio.CharBuffer) method throws an IOException then
>   the scanner assumes that the end of the input has been reached. The
>   most recent IOException thrown by the underlying readable can be
>   retrieved via the ioException() method.

Comment: which is admittedly a bit of a weird interface.

Comment: So Scanner is a bit more abstract; oriented to lexical analysis of tokens (double, int, string); not necessarily from the file system.